# Group By First Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 SELECT OrderNumber, FIRST(ShippingName) as ShippingName FROM Orders
 GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

This gives an error, how would I do this?

Comment: Please define "first" in this context.

Comment: I know what you're thinking, to use `Max()` instead, but it would be any row, but I need only 1 of them.  This example doesn't work: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp

Comment: Could you also mention the error you receive?

Comment: @RyanKenning Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, 'First' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Cause, there is no `FIRST` function in MSSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FIRST` function is not supported in SQL Server.

Maybe you want

```
SELECT OrderNumber, MIN(ShippingName) as ShippingName
FROM Orders
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

But, probably not. Instead I suspect you mean... for each `OrderNumber`, of all the rows with that `OrderNumber`, select the `ShippingName` of the first row according to some ordering.

```
SELECT OrderNumber,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 ShippingName
        FROM Orders AS OrdersInner
        WHERE OrdersInner.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
        ORDER BY OrdersInner.OrderDate, OrdersInner.OrderId
    ) as ShippingName
FROM Orders
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

But I'm making some assumptions about both your requirements and your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe mean :

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrderNumber, ShippingName
FROM Orders
ORDER BY OrderNumber DESC
```

Comment: what's the point of group by when you are selecting only top row.